# Selendroid: Deleted AVD's from AVD Manager but they are still displayed in http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/status

Tags: selendroid

Step 1 : java -jar selendroid-standalone-0.15.0-with-dependencies.jar -app app-release.apk

When I run the server from command prompt I see expected one Nexus_5_API_17 device is displayed in log.

Step 2:checking local host status http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/status

After starting the server when I check the local host for status it displays all the AVD's which are already deleted from AVD Manager and not the available one(Nexus_5_API_17).
I already checked ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME  which are set correctly.
Please let me know if I am missing anything.